# Displaying the image in search results in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-search

I am newbie to drupal 6 .Pls can any one tell me, how to display the image in search results for default search in drupal 6.I used cck module to upload the images .I got one solution by using imagecache which is not useful to me .Any help would appreciate a lot,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to display image related to specific search results or just some static image.
In both cases you can do it from search results template file I guess:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-results.tpl.php/6